# Why using ngSubmit instead of onSubmit

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Whats the reason for using `ngSubmit` to submit a form instead of using `onSubmit` at the submit button in angular 2.

Comment: Seems you mean "`onSubmit` at the ..." in your last sentence like in the question title. Please fix to avoid confusion.

Comment: Simply the reason is ngSubmit exposes submit through anguler(so angluar knows that submit has happened) and onSubmit is default binding   for basic javascript that is not bound to angular

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ngSubmit` is a in-built directive of Angular2 which is used to submit Angular2 form without clicking any submit button. You usually see it attached with `form` tag.

Why?

Consider, you have your login screen contains `username`,  `password` & `login` button. 
Once user fills in details, he has to click the `login` button to submit the form with data.  So, with `ngSubmit` directive you can submit form with data without touching or clicking the submit button. You just hit the enter and `ngSubmit` will do the job for you.

In Angular1 `ngSubmit` directive was discovered to submit form without clicking the login/any button. In Angular2 `ngSubmit` directive still exists.

Please note, with or without `ngSubmit` directive, you still can use submit button to submit the form with data. This is just a functionality given by Angular team.

Answer (score 1):

Thats is similar to a normal web form, an `action` attribute on the form which says which URL to call or on submit of the form. And a web form can also be submitted via pressing the enter/return key instead of a submit button press.

Answer (score 1):

Angular, has update the `<form>` tag with another Angular directive, NgSubmit, and bind it to the onSubmit() method..

For more [Click here](https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/guide/forms.html)